# Subtract 1 from FOR loop index in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In Windows batch, I have a `for` loop like so:

```
   for /l %%a in (0,1,337) do (

      for /F "tokens=*" %%b IN ("tile%%a.jpg") DO set size=%%~zb

      if !size! GTR 0 (
          echo Size is greater than 0
      ) ELSE (

      )

   )
```

I know this code doesn't make much sense right now, but I'm going to develop it further.  I just want to know how to subtract 1 from `%%a` in the `ELSE` statement.  Basically I want to be able to "redo" a loop number when the `IF` isn't true, if that makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the value of a loop variable. You can only modify the value of an environment variable.

But why using `for /L %%a in (0,1,337) do` at all?

Better would be for example:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (tile*.jpg) do (
    if %%~zA == 0 (
        echo File size of %%A is 0 bytes.
    ) else (
        echo File size of %%A is greater than 0.
    )
)
```

This loop processes simply all `tile*.jpg` in current directory.

But this loop can't be used if files with 0 bytes are deleted in current directory. Processing the list of `tile*.jpg` files in current directory and change the files list in the same loop is no good idea because simply not working. The solution is using command **DIR** to get first the list of all files matching the file name pattern and next process the output of **DIR** line by line using **FOR**.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B /OS tile*.jpg 2^>nul') do (
    if %%~zA == 0 (
        echo File size of %%A is 0 bytes.
    ) else (
        echo First file with more than 0 bytes is: %%A
        goto ExitLoop
    )
)
:ExitLoop
endlocal
```

The command **DIR** is executed to output the list of files matching the pattern `tile*.jpg` with ignoring directories which by chance would be matched also by this wildcard pattern because of option `/A-D` in bare format (only file name) because option `/B` in order sorted by file size because of option `/OS` from smallest to largest file.

`2^>nul` redirects the error message output by command **DIR** to handle **STDERR** on not finding any file matching the wildcard pattern to device **NUL** to suppress this error message. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character on parsing the **FOR** command line and interpreted as redirection operator on execution of **DIR** command line by **FOR**.

The loop is immediately exited once a file with more than 0 bytes is found as all further files have surely also more than 0 bytes.

One more loop can be used after label `ExitLoop` which should be renamed to something more suitable in this case for example to renumber the remaining files using command **REN** when first loop deletes files with 0 bytes.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me lots of info!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the loop variable `%%a`.  Only the loop itself can modify it.

If you want to calculate a new value you can do:

```
set /A NEW_VALUE=%%a-1
echo %NEW_VALUE%           (prove that NewValue is now 1 smaller than %%a)
```

Comment: Hint: within the `for /L` loop you will need [delayed expansion](http://ss.64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for variable `!NEW_VALUE!` as it is modified *and* read within the loop body; using `%NEW_VALUE%` returns the value present *before* the loop has even started...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a `for` variable reference like `%%a`, but you can store its value into a standard environment variable (like `index`) and modify this. For this to work you need to enable and use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), because the variable is modified *and* read within the same block of code, namely the loop body, so read it like `!index!`; using normal expansion like `%index%` returned the value present *before* the loop has even started:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%a in (0,1,337) do (
    set /A "index=%%a-1"
    echo %%a - 1 = !index!
)
endlocal
```

---

A nice alternative that avoids need of delayed expansion is to use an embedded `for /F` loop that gets the output of the subtraction and iterates once only per iteration of the surrounding `for /L` loop, like this:

```cmd
@echo off
for /L %%a in (0,1,337) do (
    for /F %%b in ('set /A "%%a-1"') do (
        echo %%a - 1 = %%b
    )
)
```

This works because the `for /F` loop executes the `set /A` command in `cmd` context, in which it returns the resulting value -- in contrast to the aforementioned approach, where `set /A` is executed in batch-file context, in which it does not output anything.